# Rust wrapper around Win32 Fiber

Tags: rust

So this one was quite rough to implement. I needed to pass an `FnOnce` to a foreign function through a `c_void` which requires double boxing. Another fun detail is that the callback is not called until someone actually calls `SwitchFiber` which isn't required to happen. So simply passing the ownership to the callback was not an option, because then it would like if it wasn't called. Instead I needed to keep track of whether the callback actually consumed the `FnOnce`, which ended up being another `Box`.

I would love some feedback to see if this code can be cleaned up in any way, perhaps reducing its complexity (or at least the amount of boxes).

````rust
use windows_sys::{
    Win32::Foundation::*,
    Win32::System::Threading::*,
};

use std::os::raw::c_void;
use crate::PlatformError;

struct FiberInternals {
    handle: *mut c_void,
    entry_point: *mut Box<dyn FnOnce()>
}

pub struct Fiber(Box<FiberInternals>);

impl Fiber {
    fn new<F>(entry_point: F) -> Result<Fiber, PlatformError>
        where F: FnOnce() -> () + 'static
    {
        let entry_point_box_box: Box<Box<dyn FnOnce()>> = Box::new(Box::new(entry_point));
        let entry_point_box_ptr = Box::into_raw(entry_point_box_box);

        let mut internals = Box::new(FiberInternals {
            handle: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            entry_point: entry_point_box_ptr
        });

        internals.handle = unsafe {
            CreateFiber(0, Some(fiber_entry_point), &mut *internals as *mut _ as *mut c_void)
        };

        if internals.handle == std::ptr::null_mut() {
            Err(PlatformError::new(unsafe { GetLastError() }))
        } else {
            Ok(Fiber(internals))
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Fiber {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if self.0.entry_point != std::ptr::null_mut() {
            let entry_point = unsafe { Box::from_raw(self.0.entry_point) };
        }
    }
}

extern "system" fn fiber_entry_point(parameter: *mut c_void) {
    unsafe {
        let mut internals =  &mut *(parameter as *mut FiberInternals);
        let entry_point = Box::from_raw(internals.entry_point);
        internals.entry_point = std::ptr::null_mut();

        entry_point();
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FiberInternals::entry_point` could simply be an `Option<Box<dyn FnOnce()>>`. In `fiber_entry_point`, you could use [`Option::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) to take ownership of the `Box` and leave a `None` in its place. You could then remove your `Drop` implementation, because the compiler will drop the `Box` automatically if the value is a `Some`.